# Crystal Report Formula field

Tags: crystal-reports, parameter-passing

I want to achieve the following in a Crystal report, please let me know if they are possible:

- Hide/Unhide a certain field based on an input parameter
- Change the content of a certain field in the page header and in the details sections based on an input parameter.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and C# 3.5

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are possible.

To hide/unhide a certain field based on a parameter value:

- create your parameter;
- right-click on the field you want to hide/unhide and select **Format Field...** from the menu;
- select the Common tab in the Format Editor;
- click on the `x-2` button to the *right* of where it says Suppress - this brings up the Formula Editor for the Suppression condition (the check box to the *left* of where it says Suppress will unconditionally suppress the field);
- enter the condition to hide the field - eg. if your parameter is called HideField and you want to hide the field if the parameter has the value 'Y', then enter `{?HideField} = 'Y'`
- click the Save and close button in the Formula Editor, and then click OK in the Format Editor.

To change the content of a certain field in the page header and in the details sections based on an input parameter, create a Crystal Formula:

- create your parameter;
- create a formula, in the form `if {?` *parameter name* `} = '` *true value* `' then {` *value1* `} else {` *value2* `}`
- insert your formula into the page header and details sections of your report where you want to see the parameterised content field.

Comment: now I got into the problem that the numbers are displayed with decimal places.

Comment: @Ahmad: right-click on the field in question and select **Format Field...**. The Format Editor dialog should include a Number tab - you can select relatively simple combinations of decimals, thousand separators and minus signs here, or you can click on the **Customize...** button to bring up the Custom Style dialog, which will give you much greater control over number formatting.

Comment: This does not solve the problem as in the formula the field is recognized as string not text. I used the string functions to trim it to my needs. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would hide a field - Without a condition - in crystal report

Right click over the field name in Crystal Reports design

1. Select Format Field...
2. Click on Common tab
3. Check off the Suppress checkbox

The field is now Hidden!

Comment: I have long gave up on crystal reports and switched to epplus.

Comment: While in itself correct, this does not answer the question asked.